# Create file export and save from ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web page that contains a grid view of user data. I need to take the data in the gridview, generate an excel file, and allow the user to save that excel file to their local machine.

What would be the best way to accomplish this in code? Would it be possible to display a file save dialogue and then create the file from the grid data after the user selects the directory and filename?  I've accomplished this in software development but never dealt with it in web development.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can implement this use filestreaming to get file data in byte then assign those byte to response. check this link it will guide you how to open file dialouge and allow user to save file on user side.http://corymathews.com/397/aspnetc-prompt-a-save-dialog-box-to-download-a-file/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most people tend to implement it like this:

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xls");

        Response.Charset = "";         
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();        
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);        
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
}
```

[Source.](http://geekswithblogs.net/azamsharp/archive/2005/12/21/63843.aspx)

Another alternative (the one I prefer) is to use [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Same exactly thing i am talking about. I also have that code but can't find it :)

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm! I was off by just a bit in my existing code. Web dev bleh. :)

Comment: +1 for EPPlus if you need more control over generated excel. It's easy to learn and use, just the way software should be.